# How to pass a where clause simply but safely via a console command in ZF2?

Tags: mysql, security, console, zend-framework2

I'm creating a quick and dirty console controller to create fixtures from a database table.

I'd like to use a where clause to limit this - but would like to make the controller a little less dirty and prevent injections.

My current console command specification is:

```
db create fixture <table_name> [--where=]
```

The controller action has:

```
$tableName = $request->getParam('table_name');
$where = $request->getParam('where');

$queryString = "select * from `$tableName`";
if (!is_null($where)) {
    $queryString .= " where $where";
}

$resultSet = $dbAdapter->query(
    $queryString,
    DbAdapter::QUERY_MODE_EXECUTE
);
```

Now, I know this is obviously wide open to SQL injection - as confirmed when I ran the following:

```
db create fixture hit_log --where="\`timestamp\` between '2015-01-20 00:00:00' and '2015-01-30 00:00:00'; delete from hit_log limit 1";
```

So, what would be a good strategy to fix this?

I'm thinking of JSON notation `--where='{"timestamp":["between","2015-01-20","2015-02-30"]}'` - but then I'll have to write a translator to handle different tests like "=", "LIKE",  and "BETWEEN".

Edit:

I've put checks in the controller action to ensure it is a console only request, and will error out if a user somehow manages to route via the http router.

This then assumes that a developer is running the command, and would have access to the database anyway. I guess this is more trying to protect against error than malice.

Comment: Use \Zend\Db\Sql\Expression? And escape your parameters.

Comment: Be carefully, prepared statement won't be able to prevent sql injection attacks through table and column names. Do not get those variables from user.

Comment: @stanimir - yeah, but I'm trying to think of a simple way to put the where clause into the command so that I can get the necessaries for Zend Expression.

Comment: @MehmetInce please elaborate? For one - that is not really a prepared statement in my example.

Comment: Can you give us examples of how `$where` and `$tableName` looks like?

Comment: well - $tableName is just the table name from the database (and is the parameter in the command after "fixture"), and currently $where is just an SQL where clause passed with "--where" argument in the command, as that was the simplest way to to get the job done - while also being the least secure...